# MUI DataGrid error when importing from component library and using GridToolbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component library package that exports a `Table` component. This component uses `DataGrid` from `@mui/x-data-grid`:

```
// Table component
import { DataGrid, DataGridProps } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

export const Table = ({ ...rest }: DataGridProps) => {
  return <DataGrid rowHeight={40} {...rest} />;
};
```

This Table component works fine in the library, specifically if I add `GridToolbar` from `@mui/x-data-grid` - this gives no issues (omitting rows/columns for brevity):

```
import { GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Table } from './Table';

//etc

<Table
 // rows, columns, etc. ...
 slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
 slotProps={{
  toolbar: {
   showQuickFilter: true,
   quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 300 },
  },
 }}
/>
```

However, when I try to import Table from my library and use that same code in a different package, lets call it AppPackage:

```
import { GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Table } from '@company/component-lib';

//etc

<Table
 // rows, columns, etc. ...
 slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
 slotProps={{
  toolbar: {
   showQuickFilter: true,
   quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 300 },
  },
 }}
/>
```

I receive this error:

```
index.tsx:36 Error: MUI: useGridRootProps should only be used inside the DataGrid, DataGridPro or DataGridPremium component.
    at useGridRootProps (useGridRootProps.js:6:1)
    at GridToolbar (GridToolbar.js:27:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14128:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:16702:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18749:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23672:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22942:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22865:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22838:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:22330:1)
```

Both the component library and AppPackage are using `"@mui/x-data-grid": "6.18.4"`. If I run `yarn link` on the component library package and `yarn link @company/component-lib` in AppPackage, it works. But as soon as I `yarn unlink @company/component-lib` I get the same problem saying I need to use GridToolbar in a Datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add `@mui/x-data-grid` to the peer dependencies of the component library.